# lazy load? / load images only when visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list of `<div>`s that contain `<img />`s and I don't want the page to be slowed down by the loading of all the images.

So, right now, I have the url to all the images in the `data-src` attribute and the `src` attribute is empty.

How can I load the image, move the contents of the `data-src` to `src` when that div or img is visible in the viewport with javascript / jquery?

By visible in the viewport, I mean when the user has scrolled to those images.

All the images are in divs, which are in a vertical list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lazy load plugin in jQuery.I think it is best suited for u

> Lazy Load is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading
>   of images in long web pages.

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)